# why arent my images showing in live server but will show when i open in default browser in vs code

Tags: html

```
<section id="what-you-do" class="steps">
     <h2 class="section-title secondary-border">What You Do</h2>
    <div>
      <img src="file:///Users/miguelpuerto/UCF-VIRT-BO-FSF-PT-08-2021-U-B/02-
```

Advanced-CSS/05-Module-Project/lesson-files/2.3/assets/images/step-1.svg" alt="" />

#### Step 1: Fill Out the Form Above.

You're already here, so why not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at html but try to use:

```
<img src="../../Users/miguelpuerto/UCF-VIRT-BO-FSF-PT-08-2021-U-B/02- "
```

use as many `../` as it takes to reach the path. `../../../../../`

Comment: <img src="../Downloads/01-04-svgs/step-1.svg" alt="" /> I got this but it still doesn't work on the live server for some reason it only shows the image on the default browser option when i open that

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to stackoverflow, please format your question.